# Add images to JSON response

Tags: php, json

Can we add images to the Json reponse ? I have made a custome JSON reponse but want to add image on some conditions like if flight in array is "AI" show image "http://sss.com/images/images/AI.png"

Any tutorial of idea will help me in this.

This is the response

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach ($obj->flightStatuses as $flightstatus) {
    echo $flightstatus->carrierFsCode,' ', $flightstatus->flightNumber,"<br>";
     if ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode=='G8')
            { echo "Goair<br>";} elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode== 'SG') {echo "Spicejet<br>";}elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode== '9W') {echo "Jetairways<br>";}
            elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode== 'S2') {echo "JetConnect<br>";}elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode== '6E') {echo "Indigo<br>";}
            elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode== 'AI') {echo "Air India<br>";};
```

How can I add image in this ?
thanks in advance,

Comment: This is the response I am generating

Answer (score 8):

JSON can include strings. Strings can include Base64 encoded binaries of images or URIs pointing to images.

```
{
    "base64": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdwnLpRPAAAAAZQTFRFAAD/////e9yZLAAAAAF0Uk5Tf4BctMsAAAABYktHRAH/Ai3eAAAACklEQVQI12NgAAAAAgAB4iG8MwAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTpjcmVhdGUAMjAxMy0wNC0yM1QxMTowMDowOSswMTowMDogwR0AAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6bW9kaWZ5ADIwMTMtMDQtMjNUMTE6MDA6MDkrMDE6MDBLfXmhAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
    "url": "http://example.com/blue_0.5_pixel.png"
}
```

(Having both, as in this example, is, however, redundant).

Comment: ...but please don't add the image data to a JSON string. Under almost no circumstances is this going to be the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please see the question I have added more info. Can we add image in that kind .?  @Quentin

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you can use the image URL in json or even the full image string if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the bytes from the image File into a `byte[]` and put that object into your `JSONObject`.

Comment: Isn't `byte[]` Java syntax?

Comment: @ling.s please see the quetion info again I have added more . Can we add image in here

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edits to your question…

You appear to be overthinking things. You just want to output (using **HTML**, not JSON) a piece of data you have in a variable.

```
<img src="http://sss.com/images/images/<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars($flightstatus->carrierFsCode);
?>.png" alt="">
```